# How do I make translatable views?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I want to have the front page view with my own title, but if I add it, it is shown for all the languages.

Is it possible to have a different title for each enabled language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the module "Configuration Translation" and then you get a tab "Translate view":

```
/admin/structure/views/view/[view]/translate
```

where you can add translations and edit the translated view.

The title is in:

**Displays -> Master Display Settings -> [View] Default Display Options -> Display title**